# I have a code that automates cookieclicker, it also clicks all the upgrades automatic. the only thing I still want to add is to click the golden cooki

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation

Does anyone know how I can add this in my code? This is the code:

```
def cookieclicker(num):
    cookie = driver.find_element_by_id("bigCookie")
    for i in range(num):
        cookie.click()

def store_upgrades():
    products = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("upgrade")
    for upgrade in products:
        upgrade.click()

def upgrades():
    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("enabled")
    for item in items[::-1]:
        item.click()

#main loop
def main():
    while True:
        cookieclicker(80)

        try:
            upgrades()
        except:
            continue

        try:
            store()
        except:
            continue


        if keyboard.is_pressed("q"):
            break

main()
```

As you can see the code consists of 4 function which click the cookie and buys all the upgrades. It would be great if anyone could help with the last step, the golden cookie!

Comment: Dont mind the mistake on the second try & except, I forgot to rename the function there

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Can you share the web page please

Comment: the webpage is: https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/

Comment: The question is how I can code it so it clicks the golden cookie automatic

Comment: it would need to play this game to see this golden cookie. How long it needs to play to see it?

Comment: I run it and observed HTML and it seems it shows golden cookie in `<div id="shimmers">` - it adds `<div class="shimmer" alt="Golden cookie">` so you can search it even using xpath `//div[@alt="Golden cookie"]`

Answer (score 0):

I run game and observed HTML and it seems it shows golden cookie in

```
<div id="shimmers">
```

and it adds

```
<div class="shimmer" alt="Golden cookie" ...>
```

so you could search it using class `shimmer`

```
try:
   find_element_by_class_name('shimmer').click()
except:
   pass
```

or using xpath `//div[@alt="Golden cookie"]` if you selected English language.
In other languages it uses native name - i.e in Polish it uses `alt="Złote ciastko"`.

```
try:
   find_element_by_xpath('//div[@alt="Golden cookie"]').click()
except:
   pass
```

But I didn't test if it work.

---

HTML in `DevTool`:

[image]

Full browser:

[image]